# Does SQLAlchemy sanitize raw SQL?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-injection

Simply put. If i did something like

```
Conn.execute(RAW_SQL)
```

would sqlalchemy sanitize this to prevent sql injection or does it literally just execute it?
Thanks

Comment: there is no way to magically "sanitize" a single string of SQL.  what does "sanitize" mean?  remove the dirty parts?  ok, what do dirty parts look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, if you pass in raw SQL with values interpolated, SQL Alchemy will **not** sanitise it. It'll just be executed.

Always use query parameters, at the very least.

A string object is passed straight to the underlying database connection implementation; it *does* support query parameters but you'll have to use the parameter style specific to the library that handles the database communication.

You can use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) to generate SQL with implementation agnostic query parameter syntax.